# In cordova add platform then get mess "Adding android project..." but that is not added the platform

Tags: android, cordova, platform

In `cordova` when add the platform , I get the message in CMD

> Adding android project...

[image: console_image]

but not added the platform `android`. so how can i add this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add platform inside the project.

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
```

check your platform

```
cordova platform ls
```

Comment: yah, i am work in inside the project. but when i type  " cordova platform add android " , then get mess " Adding android project... " but not add the platform actually .....

Comment: cordova platfrom ls :- android 5.1.1

Comment: hello1/platforms/android

Comment: i cant understand , what u are saying. i m fresher in phonegap.

Comment: try this url https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Comment: ok Tx sir/mem.................